# Homogeneous components of a module

Tags: modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity.
Can anybody please help me giving a definition of what the **homogeneous component** of an $R$-module $M$ is. I searched for the definition but I never got it.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

The citation below is taken out of a paper not a book.

[image]

Comment: See the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_module) for graded modules. The idea is that if $M$ is graded as $M = \bigoplus M_i$, then each fixed $M_i$ is a **homogeneous component** of $M$.

Comment: For a semisimple module it could also refer to the submodules which are sums of mutually isomorphic simple submodules.

Comment: I edited the post. The module is not necessarily semisimple. @rschwieb . Also, what is meant precisely by "complete sum". I'm actually familiar with "internal direct sum" and "external direct sums".